# Can I create a front end JavaScript application that triggers a hidden request to another WebPage to scrape data from?

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, puppeteer

I want to Web Scrape a website, and already have a working puppeteer implementation in javaScript. However, I was wondering if its possible to instead host a JS application with a simple button for the user to click. This button could theoretically trigger a hidden request to the other webpage and scrape the required data without the need to launch another headless browser?

Is there another method that could potentially achieve similar functionality?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question.  What technical issue are you asking about?  It may be helpful to put in more details about what are you doing.